# Can I use lambda, map, apply, or applymap to fill a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a simplified version of my data. I have a dataframe of coordinates, and an empty dataframe which should be filled with the distance of each pair using the function provided.

What is the quickest method to fill this dataframe? As much as possible, I want to stay away from nested for loops (slow!). Can I use apply or applymap? 
You may modify the function or other parts accordingly. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_distance(point1, point2):
    """Gets the coordinates of two points as two lists, and outputs their distance"""
    return (((point1[0] - point2[0]) ** 2 + (point1[1] - point2[1]) ** 2 + (point1[2] - point2[2]) ** 2) ** 0.5)

#Dataframe of coordinates.    
df = pd.DataFrame({"No.": [25, 36, 70, 95, 112, 101, 121, 201], "x": [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5], "y": [2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6], "z": [3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7]})
df.set_index("No.", inplace = True)

#Dataframe to be filled with each pair distance.
df_dist = pd.DataFrame({'target': [112, 101, 121, 201]}, columns=["target", 25, 36, 70, 95])
df_dist.set_index("target", inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use for loops, you can compute the distances between all the possible pairs in the following way.

You first need to do the cartesian product of `df` with itself to have all the possible pairs of point.

```
i, j = np.where(1 - np.eye(len(df)))
df=df.iloc[i].reset_index(drop=True).join(
    df.iloc[j].reset_index(drop=True), rsuffix='_2')
```

Where `i` and `j` are the boolean indexes of the upper and lower triangles of a square matrix of size `len(df)`. After you did this you just need to apply your distance function

```
df['distance'] = get_distance([df['x'],df['y'],df['z']], [df['x_2'],df['y_2'],df['z_2']])
df.head()

No. x   y   z   No._2   x_2 y_2 z_2 distance
0   25  1   2   3   36  2   3   4   1.732051
1   25  1   2   3   70  3   4   5   3.464102
2   25  1   2   3   95  4   5   6   5.196152
3   25  1   2   3   112 2   3   4   1.732051
4   25  1   2   3   101 3   4   5   3.464102
```

If you wanted to compute only the points from df_dist you can modify accordingly the matrix `1 - np.eye(len(df))`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no clear speed benefit of lambda over a for loop - and it's very hard to write a double lambda, usually that is reserved for straightforward row operations.

However with some engineering, we can reduce our code to a few simple and self explanatory lines:

```
import numpy as np

get = lambda i: df.loc[i,:].values
dist = lambda i, j: np.sqrt(sum((get(i) - get(j))**2))
# Fills your df_dist
for i in df_dist.columns:
    for j in df_dist.index:
        df_dist.loc[j,i] = dist(i, j)
```

The resulting `df_dist`:

```
              25        36        70        95
target                                        
112     1.732051  0.000000  1.732051  3.464102
101     3.464102  1.732051  0.000000  1.732051
121     5.196152  3.464102  1.732051  0.000000
201     6.928203  5.196152  3.464102  1.732051
```